# Amazon Affiliate Link Builder python script crashing?

Tags: python

I really wonder why sometimes my python script is crashing.

```py
def returnAmazonLink(link):

    if 'amazon.de' in link:
        art, tracking_id, endung = 'amazon-ref.de', 'myID', '.de'
    elif 'amazon.co.uk' in link:
        art, tracking_id, endung = 'amazon-ref.co.uk', 'myID', '.co.uk'
    elif 'amazon.es' in link:
        art, tracking_id, endung = 'amazon-ref.es', 'myID', '.es'
    elif 'amazon.fr' in link:
        art, tracking_id, endung = 'amazon-ref.fr', 'myID', '.fr'
    elif 'amazon.it' in link:
        art, tracking_id, endung = 'amazon-ref.it', 'myID', '.it'
    else:
        art = 'amazon-ERROR'
        offer_link = link
        return offer_link, art

    try:
        split_a = link.split('/dp/')
        asin = split_a[1][0:10]
        offer_link = 'https://www.amazon'+ endung +'/dp/' + asin + '/?tag=' + tracking_id
    except:
        try:
            split_b = link.split('/product/')
            asin = split_b[1][0:10]
            offer_link = 'https://www.amazon'+ endung+'/gp/product/' + asin + '/?tag=' + tracking_id
        except:
            split_c = link.split('/offer-listing/')
            asin = split_c[1][0:10]
            offer_link = 'https://www.amazon'+ endung +'/gp/offer-listing/' + asin + '/?tag=' + tracking_id

    return offer_link, art
```

I expect to get an amazon affiliate url when calling the method like returnAmazonLink[0]

A sample input could be:
`https://www.amazon.de/Marshall-Tufton-Tragbarer-Lautsprecher-Schwarz/dp/B07PZCRG6X?pf_rd_p=fd924cef-3db6-4a05-a84c-ae526862ddd8&pd_rd_wg=2ga3n&pf_rd_r=T28M0D83M3NG8JJVX04K&ref_=pd_gw_cr_simh&pd_rd_w=NmDeI&pd_rd_r=3974ee63-3d1d-4b9e-b536-b5bd73e18b3f`

Its only crashing sometimes... Not all the time. 
I think so problem is with the try catches, as this is stated in the occuring error message also.

But its showing me the error as you can see on the image.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6D67.png)

I really hope you guys can help me!
Thanks a lot

Comment: what is your input?

Comment: A normal link from a product! Sorry, I should've add this.

Comment: add the input you sending to the function in your question :)

Comment: I did that .. :)

Answer (score 1):

i think its a wried thing to write an `exception base code`

your input is probably doesnt contains any of '/dp/' or '/product/' or '/offer-listing/'
which makes the problem

i would try to do it as :

```py
if '/dp/' in link:
    split_a = link.split('/dp/')
    asin = split_a[1][0:10]
    offer_link = 'https://www.amazon'+ endung +'/dp/' + asin + '/?tag=' + tracking_id
elif '/product/' in link:
    split_b = link.split('/product/')
    asin = split_b[1][0:10]
    offer_link = 'https://www.amazon'+ endung+'/gp/product/' + asin + '/?tag=' + tracking_id
elif '/offer-listing/' in link:
    split_c = link.split('/offer-listing/')
    asin = split_c[1][0:10]
    offer_link = 'https://www.amazon'+ endung +'/gp/offer-listing/' + asin + '/?tag=' + tracking_id
else:
    print('There was an error! check this link:')
    print(link)
    art = 'amazon-ERROR'
    offer_link = link
```

Comment: could be. are you able to see the picture of the occuring error i uploaded? I dont know how that works here

Comment: @MaxPeterNoid What input makes you get this exception?

Comment: sadly I dont know that exactly. Because I run it with so many inputs...

Comment: @MaxPeterNoid checkout my edit, i added some log that can help you spot the mistake, i think now you can run it and it should work and you will get to know when your input is invalid